# Problems running a stored procedure owned by another user

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, sql-server-2000

We have a 3rd-party app that wants to call a stored proc using SQL 2005-style "schema" syntax:

```
Customer.InsertNewOrder
```

This db is still on SQL 2000, though, so we're trying to make it "look" like a SQL 2005 schema, and still work right (with minimum necessary permissions). So we:

1. Created a user called "Customer"
2. Created the stored proc owned by that user
3. Granted the web user "execute" rights on the stored proc (via a role)

Granting our web user execute rights is usually all that is takes to run dbo-owned procs (like "dbo.InsertOrder"). We don't usually have to grant explicit permissions on the underlying tables. But it doesn't seem to work in this case. We're getting an error:

```
INSERT permission denied on object "Order"
```

So what am I doing wrong?

How can I tell *what* user is being denied here. Is it my WebUser? Or is it "executing as" the **Customer** user, and the Customer user needs additional permissions? (I tried granting additional permission to the Customer user (db_datareader and db_datawriter, even tried db_owner), but that didn't seem to help. db_owner isn't an option in production, anyway.)

I suppose I can grant explicit INSERT permissions on the necessary table, but why would this be necessary in this case, when it isn't the case for a DBO owned proc?

**EDIT:**
I've simplified for the sake of this question. In reality, I have several dozen stored procs under two different "schemas" that insert, update, and select from many tables. So hoping to not have to manually itemize permissions on all, if I can help it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "When one user owns the source object
>   and all target objects, the ownership
>   chain is said to be unbroken. If
>   different users own the target
>   objects, the ownership chain is
>   broken. SQL Server relies on the state
>   of the ownership chain to determine
>   when to check permissions. 
>   
>  (snip) 
>   If
>   the ownership chain is broken, SQL
>   Server checks permissions on each
>   branch of the chain owned by a
>   different user. Only those statements
>   where the user has the necessary
>   permissions will be executed, and the
>   remaining statements will get an
>   "Insufficient Permissions" error. In this way, SQL Server allows object owners to retain control over permissions."

Quoted from [Using Ownership Chains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905173(SQL.80).aspx)

To apply this to the current scenario, when the **Customer.InsertOrder** proc attempts to insert into the **dbo.Order** table, this breaks the ownership chain, and SQL checks to see if the *original user* (WebUser, in this case) has permission to perform the insert.

So WebUser (not Customer) will need permission to INSERT into dbo.Order (either explicitly, or via db_datawriter). All permissions can be removed from Customer, if desired.

Comment: Explicitly grant insert permissions on your table to user Customer.

Answer (score -1):

It's the Customer user. It needs datawriter access to the Order table.

Comment: But the Customer user already is already a member of the database-level db\_datawriter role. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: What happens if you reference the Order table as dbo.Order from the InsertNewOrder sp?

Comment: Not sure. Don't want to do this if I don't have to, as this is only 1 of a couple dozen procs (I simplified for the sake of the question). You are correct, though, the stored proc doesn't use a fully-qualified table name.

Comment: Nope. Was the WebUser, not the Customer user.

Comment: Apols. I was sure sp's ran in the user context of their owner. I thought that you could prevent access to a table from a user directly but give access to some data via an sp. Maybe it's the lowest rights of the calling connection and owner or something..? But doesn't really make sense...

Comment: One of the things I ran into was an option to "EXECUTE AS OWNER" option, but I think that only applies to SQL 2005 and above...